# No insertion point in styled text input on IE 9 and below

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, textinput

Here's a demo:
http://codepen.io/raddevon/pen/ujwqA

The insertion point is not visible for this styled text input control in versions of IE below 10. The input control otherwise behaves as it should. I can enter text into it despite not being able to see the insertion point. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the `text-align: right` property that causes the insertion point to be invisible in older versions of IE. I override this to `text-align: left` in my IE stylesheet to fix the problem.